# How to turn the Vega timeline example of the first five US Presidents into one of the first five Canadian Prime Ministers?

Tags: timeline, vega

https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/timelines/ shows a timeline visualization of the lifespans of the first five U.S. presidents, including the years each held office.

But I would like the same thing for [the first five Canadian Prime Ministers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_ministers_of_Canada#Timeline).  The difference being: each US president entered and left office only *once*; one of the first five Canadian Prime Ministers entered and left office *multiple* times.

How can we show multiple separate terms in office on any single given birth-to-death timeline?

For example, let's say Adams was in office for a second time (instead of Madison having been in office).

Currently in that example, Adams is given as

```
    {
      "label": "Adams",
      "born": -7389766800000,
      "died": -4528285200000,
      "enter": -5453884800000,
      "leave": -5327740800000
    }
```

Had history been somehow different such that Adams returned to office precisely when, if fact, Madison was in office, how would we specify that?   Perhaps:

```
    {
      "label": "Adams",
      "born": -7389766800000,
      "died": -4528285200000,
      "enter": -5453884800000,
      "leave": -5327740800000,
      "enter": -5075280000000,
      "leave": -4822819200000
    },
```

Or maybe . . .

```
    {
      "label": "Adams",
      "born": -7389766800000,
      "died": -4528285200000,
      "presidencies" : [
        {"enter": -5453884800000, "leave": -5327740800000},
        {"enter": -5075280000000, "leave": -4822819200000}
      ]
    }
```

?

Or is it some other part of the Vega code that would have to change instead or in addition?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have unlimited terms for each president, have a dataset "terms" with each record being a president's term of office:

```
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "people",
      "values": [
        {"label": "Washington", "born": -7506057600000, "died": -5366196000000},
        {"label": "Adams", "born": -7389766800000, "died": -4528285200000},
        {"label": "Jefferson", "born": -7154586000000, "died": -4528285200000},
        {"label": "Madison", "born": -6904544400000, "died": -4213184400000},
        {"label": "Monroe", "born": -6679904400000, "died": -4370518800000}
      ]
    },

   {
      "name": "terms",
      "values": [
        {"label": "Washington", "enter": -5701424400000, "leave": -5453884800000},
        {"label": "Adams", "enter": -5453884800000, "leave": -5327740800000},
        {"label": "Adams", "enter": -5175280000000, "leave": -5022819200000},
        {"label": "Adams", "enter": -4800000000000, "leave": -4700000000000},
        {"label": "Jefferson","enter": -5327740800000, "leave": -5075280000000},
        {"label": "Madison", "enter": -5075280000000, "leave": -4822819200000},
        {"label": "Madison", "enter": -4570358400000, "leave": -4300000000000},
        {"label": "Monroe", "enter": -4822819200000, "leave": -4570358400000}
      ]
    },
```

For mark "rect", change the data source from "people" to "terms"

```
{
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "terms"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "enter"},
          "x2": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "leave"},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "label", "offset": -1},
          "height": {"value": 4},
          "fill": {"value": "#e44"}
        }
      }
    }
```

[View in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAEahHAA2NcXG3EaEBkiMAvJGona2AM13xtR0hCev6p5zSKEJjaAaTaAKqUAMqU2jiKCjTy4pgQlNIgAO7J9GgCAAwFMvA0ZFhoABzFIDhIsrLGZPkysvYoqADaoOJI+mi1cGw4BnCZxNYMCmjdIAZITIYDAOpIEDBNmBKZTGyKGgC0AOyFAGwFAkfnRUWtNHCyaAcCAMynpwCMAJzXNwUAvlJQPNFgYBpo2ggIDs9ocji9Kl8rqdqn87g8ngAWAQAJkqeNxfwBQLmCyW6AAUnBnM44EFtjJdvsnkcPgJsZVfjd0Y9UAdsXiCTiiYDgWSwegALL1CwMkBMw6nL4FbGYtVEnlYnEfF4fSrqv6i0mggaSiSKNhjRmwp7vI5fZUG7lye68-kvI4XPWom7-AC6Rt6-XQmDpUPGk2mXTFJvQq3WmzlcFSdKelwKH0xOKdtzmcCQpDT2IR+p9RSNIPJIAhfWhMmTocURdelVLGrzBbGfNeOKOR0xBTLxJjVZr4frKab3Y+JzxRNzo07aYKOLx32FhpJlYl1chdZADdTfMxQ-nMkXhePnvnm5HO6pNLpYkkE8baZevf7g-bF67zwKs6nsOxpVtKjTPpkh5Tv+gE3ue+aXvy+Jrl8G6+lu4qmjKEGvke-Lpi8Aj6j+CF-piLw3reIE7ma4gWlaB6TliyGVOuJFLseBFEQOhoBiSQZdgepCpPuzh7MgmBoKAmAAJ44IJohynUQRdqAWTwBocj2GM-yAiAEwGFM0LRiAAkDAAInAUAGHELjaAAkuI8jyU5yZQAx6nJgMFIMAYMnaJiUjaDOVwgIGfSCVEsTaAAwhIwR0AwDgvtkGkDC8BCYgQM6ImF-ERQMAAybAMBYNBIL02gAAoMIosBrB5aVaAkNAGNoFFBXqBQvHlPQFVK5qWto5lsFAmDKCYmSeZpllQNoOKdfiPX+v6MjQNYUazGZ6AyetoyZLJ8kDEwFWPDIigVWQXadMUoAQGUvQ7qU5SSatchsMgxhSVpmAdIMwz7TIASGLy1FheFwYgAAHntDGHYJegMRd4hXQMOSyHk50lU5aDjVMrQfUgX2oKAbS-QM8kAwxwMGLIxmdPKNqagGb1IFDm2gHs9ypMdbDYB9mSwwMMNQBtmRiYoEkDAApAAmmFfoyMgigANb09JckI3AUOSUDFoIN9ZN-XAwlpHljFQGw8jfVB31Q99QvoCLYtA-ctNo2lekyd9BlTE8HzEiAl37ST+mRk8OICHpAQGBKoC+4JADENzm6GOvfTToNmdHEiYNENA2KpYeGV2Ae6bpJLwwMiRjeL+uG+0Awmw20J6W5VtF7bof26HjvQ0Lrsgx7Xlez74d8pUeno3kocJ2gHx6c9FSh5n31kBaDA4AMS+vTILjOBAcCSagk+u7HY8lwMietpU4MVxrR0htrusgM49eh0bFNDCMOkTpb1uhy7qAHud1RYh37mA6mbtQYKnNt7XukCBi7UQYPd26BtyZH3ofY+BwXjR1anHYuft0DJyKKnZ+GdoEDAwTnVI+dC4X2IWXculdNbVysi-N+AsP6N3QJTH+5t24ANAEA6GDtEFOwHq-Kh6BYF6ShjicRYtJEoOkUPdAjQMSjwQcokAyCXZqLQWDRecAyjL3juPHE+Dz6z3HiAROAhLh3yNFXdANdOHv1JrwkAjZwxt3EP-TuTFu5KPAc7QGhjQa23kYonRYSpGr3QaROBoTBL6IiYksGe8aTYP9iYsxx8LGX1QJiaxhC54kLgGqZxAYgA)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simply add more data fields for each president such as

```
  "enter2": -4570358400000,
  "leave2": -4300000000000
```

and add additional mark "rect" to render the extra data, e.g.

```
{
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "people"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "enter2"},
          "x2": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "leave2"},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "label", "offset":-1},
          "height": {"value": 4},
          "fill": {"value": "magenta"}
        }
      }
    }
```

[View in Vega online Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-UaKAbTDQMcFjZxASGLIJGdCAjqqSejzfj1IBIAtuWzHs9ypBVbDYH1mTLQMS1QDlmSgYo4EDAApAAmuJmUgMgigANbPVBsFrXAC0QSBG4IINV0jQBOLsvh7FsPIg0toNC2DZD6DQ7DE2PTt3H4dBg2EVMTwfEaMh1SVqCgELPaQgI+EBMSguTPBADENz6SAuLE4ND1TQMRma6BqTRDQNhoQRKtoKLeF4QZq0DIkkVw2TFPtAM1NAZr9OM1LN64vKoCs377MgJz40gHr01xZrAt+zLTyVPhu15PHVuoB8+GlOUEF+1Hg1kBuDA4AM2fdTILjOBAcC50nE1K2nRFq2ilRzXb+Pleg2sk5Hrt+5TN1DCMuGylADMW8zfvB81MOS2HkPc-r6BvbHbOz-BRXr3Dk3TcuTIV9a1e5wcLwKx5mbS+nIDq0Umvd7rO8DHvRsSJgpvm8rTfW0atv2wTjvUR7s4Pul13boFusPb24gx6+1AJPIOa9YYcwXpHR+y9Cz4QWhSGeSD55b0XtND6q8Q5b0Kig-O6Bn5Z06jnT+wtUCQjPg3S+X90CqwEJcNuaYHboCdkAkBQ0RoQJKnTaB48ma3inogue4d7poP9mGTB2CQCh1kdvHmlC4wjxAHHHBc9N5c1QRomaSwD5VxriLahXVc4sPoeCJhF9LasOvnAGEXC-6dxAHwl24N+5gNGpA0RMCJ6SIQSQ3BaiCEezlPiJR0j4KRKMUvdUmpYkyF0So0hOjyHyOfmYo+liSg0IqI3OxDi6HwWQPVVIKBbbpWpEAA)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Roy.   This solves the problem.   But would you still recommend this technique if the premierships could number in the tens or hundreds for any given Prime Minister?  I was wondering if there was a way to avoid the tens or hundreds of `mark` `rect`s that differ from each other only by the `field` of their `x` and `x2`.